# Как загрузить и вывести ссылку из бд?

Tags: php

Как мне вывести правильно ссылку из БД? Есть такой код, но сайт выдаёт ошибку при попытке вывести

```
 echo ' <br> Голод: '.$user['golod'].' <br> Действия: "<a href = 'https://".$user['my_location']."'></a>"; <br> <br>;
 <br>';
```

---

Сайт выдаёт ошибку при попытке открыть вот такую ссылку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Функции `htmlspecialchars`, `htmlentities` и `urlencode` вам в помошь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было бы интересно посмотреть на ошибку, но судя по всему, Вы запутались в одинарных кавычках. Попробуйте так:

```
echo '<br> Голод: '.$user['golod'].' <br> Действия: <a href="https://'.$user['my_location'].'">Ссылка</a> <br> <br> <br>';
```